# Override Swift dictionary creation to not allow nil

Tags: swift, dictionary

In this playground example I'm hoping to find an extension that will remove any nils I put into the creation of a dictionary.

```
var someValue: String?

if false {
   someValue = "test"
}

var dict = ["key": "value",
            "key2": someValue]
print("\(dict)")
dict["key3"] = nil

print("\(dict)")
```

In the above code the current log is

```
[AnyHashable("key2"): nil, AnyHashable("key"): Optional("value")]
[AnyHashable("key2"): nil, AnyHashable("key"): Optional("value")]
```

key3 is never added because setting = nil tells it to be removed.  I would like to add that functionality to the initial creation of the dictionary but have yet to find a solution that works.

A working solution would result in the following print out

```
[AnyHashable("key"): Optional("value")]
[AnyHashable("key"): Optional("value")]
```

Comment: If you don't want `nil` values in the dictionary, why are you adding them and why do you declare `dict` to allow optional values?

Comment: This was a very basic example but essentially we could remove the type declaration and add an optional value to the dictionary.  This would result in the type being [AnyHashable: Any?] without explicitly setting it.  We were previously handling this by adding checks such as `user.name ?? ""` to avoid adding nils but the inline checks were increasing compile time.

Comment: This strongly suggests your misusing Dictionary, which is also the answer to your "why does it work this way?" (because you're not supposed to use Dictionary this way) In most cases, `[AnyHashable: Any]` is a mistake (it shows up when interoperating w/ Cocoa, but should be converted to something else, usually a struct, immediately). But sometimes it makes sense. But raising this to `Any?` is madness. `Optional` is *itself* an `Any`, and anything can lift to `Optional`, so the opportunities for subtle bugs (like this small difference) are extreme.

Comment: I've updated my sample code to hopefully help explain what I'm attempting to avoid have happen.  Let me know if this clears anything up @RobNapier.  Also the reason I'm concerned about having nils is because the libraries that handle these dictionaries are still in Objective-C so ideally when we are fully Swift this will no longer be a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not solvable in Swift. The correct way to write it is:

```
var dict = ["key": "value"]
if false {
    dict["key2"] = "test"
}
```

Swift doesn't provide the kind of syntax you're describing, and trying to force it to is going to break the type and create buggy situations. Do not try to create `[AnyHashable: Any?]`. That is a completely broken type that's going to burn you (`Any?` is completely broken as a type because `Optional` is `Any`, and anything can implicitly become Optional, so it becomes a bizarre recursive rabbit hole). `[AnyHashable: Any]` is acceptable if you must bridge to `NSDictionary`, but in general it should be strongly avoided and limited to just where you need it.

Note that this was much even more broken in ObjC (you could write this kind of stuff, but then it'd crash or truncate your dictionary, or some other weird bug), so at least we're making some progress.

In a lot of cases when I see people run into this problem, it's because they've overused optionals in the first place. In your `user.name` example, why is `name` optional in the first place? Is there any difference between nil and ""? If there isn't (and there usually isn't), then just make `name` non-optional (nonnullable in ObjC) and default it to empty and lots of problems go away. Having two versions of the same value (i.e. nil and "" have the same meaning) indicates a type problem, not a syntax problem.

---

If you want to simplify the syntax just a little bit with a quick extension that works on key/value? pairs like this:

```
extension Dictionary {
    init(keyOptionalPairs: [(Key, Value?)]) {
        var d: [Key: Value] = [:]
        for (key, value) in keyOptionalPairs {
            d[key] = value
        }
        self = d
    }
}

let keyValues: [(String, String?)] = [
    ("key", "value"),
    ("key2", nil)
]

let dict = Dictionary(keyOptionalPairs: keyValues)
```

But notice that the Dictionary is `[String: String]`, not `[String: String?]`. That's on purpose.

Compared to your syntax, it just adds a set of parens. But compare to the non-fancy version, which isn't beautiful, but is very straightforward.

```
let dict: [String: String] = {
    var d: [String: String] = [:]
    d["key"] = "value"
    d["key2"] = nil
    return d
}()
```

Comment: I completely agree with the above.  Some cases are a little more intricate than just making `name` non optional.  An example being we have an object that when provided by the api may or may not exist.  We're attempting to add the ID of that object into the dictionary.  It seems like the only way to really handle scenarios like that would be to make the creation of the dictionary much more verbose by calling out each addition of an optional such as this example into a `dict[key] = object.optionalSubObject.ID` and let that either be added or not depending on if it is nil or not.

Comment: Unless you know otherwise ^?

Comment: Not sure why that's particularly more verbose. Name the dictionary `d` and the number of characters are really similar to a literal. Or create an array of tuples `[(key, value?)]` and build up the dictionary at the end with a loop (which is a trivial `init` extension method if you want it).

Answer (score 0):

In Swift The Programming Language Book, I quote:

> You can use subscript syntax to remove a key-value pair from a dictionary by assigning a value of nil for that key

They said that assigning a value to nil while remove the pair, but it is not mentioned while initializing the dictionary, so I think it is not valid.

If you really need to do that, I suggest to do some logic after initializing the dictionary to do that for you, like that:

```
for (key, value) in dict {
    if value == nil {
        dict[key] = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea it seems like they're forcing me down a path like this.  I'm curious as to why initializing with a literal is allowing nil while the other treatment of setting a value of nil for a key means to remove it.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. But notice that removing the pair by assigning the value to nil is the special case, Swift's compiler treat it in special way by removing the pair. But I don't know why not the same happen while initialization.